# Safari mobile plugin development

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I want to develop a Safari plugin using Xcode or something else, and I want to access hardware functions like the Camera, is that possible? Also, are there any nice tutorials out there for plugin development under Safari mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load any kind of plugin on Mobile Safari. (This is why Flash doesn't exists yet).